# Facebook image share is not working

Tags: php

I have tried to share a post with image from my website, but only image is not getting shared, I checked the og:image on view source it comes on the view source, but it's not coming on the share box and shared post.

I also tried facebook debug, but no luck

Page link:
http://www.anothercrush.com/polling-detail/second-post

Steps:

1. Fill the 3 fields and submit
2. Now you can able to see the facebookshare button above the image, just click it
3. now you'll the issue(blank box instead of image) on the share box.

Please find the solution

Comment: *"Steps..."* - Errrr. no. You tagged as php, so post your code. Visiting a site contains rendered HTML/PHP, not source.

Comment: Hi
This is the code i am using for share
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">function fbs_click()
            {u=location.href+'/<?=date("ymdhis");?>';t='<?=$title;?>';window.open
            ('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+
            encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),
            'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');}</script>

Comment: Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

```
   This code works for me you can try
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://domain.com"/>  
    <meta property="og:title" content="PageTitle"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=" Description"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="image path"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="title" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="correct facebook app id"/>
```

Facebook console [This is usefull to check your link Facebook console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

i checked your meta tags in page view source  but i did not found the og:image property and if you  pass only this ?u= then other will fetch from og tags so please follow this or pass all the parameter you want, if you do not pass other parameter, it will search in page whatever found first, like your image working now.

Another way to share and call this method shareOnFacebookUser() on your click

```
    var appId='FACEBOOK_ID';
       window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId: appId, // App ID from the app dashboard      
                status: true, // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml: true   // Look for social plugins on the page
            });       
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

          function shareOnFacebookUser() {
            var img = $("#image").val();
            var link = $("#link").val();
            var title = $("#name").val();
            var desc = $("#desc").val();
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                link: link,
                name: title,
                picture: img,
                description:desc

            }, function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                }
                else {
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi SRK,
Thanks for your reply, i have this code already my problem is the image is getting pulled on the feed page after shared the post, but when i click the share button the image is not getting pulled on facebook share box. the share box shows only title and description, if i share the post the image comes on feed, i just want to show it on share box

Comment: can you share javascript code the share button to check

Comment: First 2 times when i click the share button image is not getting pulled on the share box, but if i click share button 3rd time it's getting pulled, i just want to know why it's getting pulled first 2 times and how can fix it.

Comment: This is the code i am using for share
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">function fbs_click()
            {u=location.href+'/<?=date("ymdhis");?>';t='<?=$title;?>';window.open
            ('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+
            encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),
            'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');}</script>

Comment: i check your meta tags but do not found the og:image property

Comment: Hi SRK, Is there any solutions?

Comment: hi raja can you move meta tags of facebook to upward then test it

Comment: I tried that also but no luck, still it shows only title and description

Comment: Hi i have share another way of share please check this.